# Cover and extension of a Lie group

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, exact-sequence, spectral-sequences, k-theory

We know that $SU(2)$ is a double cover of $SO(3)$, such that $$SU(2)/Z_2=SO(3),$$ through a finite extension $N=Z_2$.

For other examples of simply-connected Lie groups such as $SU(2)$, $SU(N)$ or $E_8$,

> (1) are there nontrivial extensions of $SU(2)$, $SU(3)$, $SU(N)$ or $E_8$?
>
> (2) are there nontrivial finite extensions of $SU(2)$, $SU(3)$, $SU(N)$ or $E_8$?

Please provide examples or counter-statements saying why they do not exist.